# checking divisibility by prime factorisation

Tags: algorithm, math

to check the divisibility of an integer (say A) by another integer(say B) , i have tried an approach by factoring B and checking if A is divisible by all the prime factors of B . However i'm not sure if its correct ? Could you please suggest what can be done ? For e.g if we have a very large integer say 10^100 and we want to check if its divisible by another integer say 200 then i was trying if 10^100 is divisible by 2 and 5 (by noticing the last digit). 
If A is small enough we could directly have checked if A%B==0 but i was trying this for larger numbers.
Thanks,

Comment: it is incorrect. take this example A=22, B=4. Prime factors of B is 2. So your algorithm will give wrong answer

Comment: Use a library for arbitrary-precision length arithmetic http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic#Libraries

Comment: I don't get it.  Why not just test `(A mod B == 0)` ?

Comment: @Andrew: because i believe we cannot do so if the number is too large for languages not supporting BigInt

Comment: I still don't get it, with what type are you storing A and B if the language does not support BigInt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to count the number of times that the prime appears in the factorization of `B`, and ensure that it appears at least as many times in the factorization of `A`.

So, 200 = 2<sup>3</sup> * 5<sup>2</sup>. Then `A` is divisible by 200 if and only if it is divisible by 2<sup>3</sup> and by 5<sup>2</sup>.

Unless you somehow know the factorization already, factorizing `A` is far slower than just dividing it by `B`. The reason is that it will take many trial divisions (or equivalent work) to fully factorize `A`, whereas it only takes one trial division to check it for divisibility by `B`. After all, consider the case where `B` is prime: you've found *all* prime factors of `A`, when all you needed was to test whether or not `B` is one of them. This cannot possibly be less work.

Comment: I was wondering about the usefulness of factorisation myself. I can only see it helping for trivial factors (such as 2, obviously).

Comment: @Neil: right, this approach would be useful if `A` and `B` were generated and stored in terms of their prime factors. Probably not otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best idea about integer factorization, written here is to let more people know and participate.

A New Way of the integer factorization
1+2+3+4+……+k=Ny,(k

True gold fears fire, you can test `1+2+3+...+k=Ny(k<N/2)`.

How do I know "k" and "y"?

"P" is a factor of "N",`GCD(k,N)=P`.

The idea may be a more simple way faster than Fermat's factorization `method(x^2-N=y^2)`!

True gold fears fire, you can test `1+2+3+...+k=Ny(k<N/2)`.

More details of the process in my G+ and BLOG.

Comment: Please see the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page for how to include links in your posts.